# Web Api - binding.query returning html

Tags: soap-api, c#, web

Im building a component to extract data from SF using C#, however when i execute the query i just get HTML returned and the following error:

Client found response content type of 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message

```
sSOQL = "Select Id, Site_Reference_Number__c, Name, Status__c From Site__c Where RECORDTYPENAME__C = 'Convenience'"
binding = new SforceService();
binding.Timeout = 60000;

binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();

binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = ReadToken();
binding.Url = ReadURL();
binding.QueryOptionsValue = new QueryOptions();
binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSize = 2000;
binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSizeSpecified = true;
QueryResult qr = new QueryResult();
qr = binding.query(sSOQL);
```

The login appears to be happening correctly as it shows as success in the login history, so im stumped as to what could be the issue. Any ideas??

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the actual value you're setting binding.Url to (returned from ReadURL()), sounds like that's wrong, it should be something like `https://{instance}.salesforce.com/services/Soap/{u or c}/{version#}`

Comment: Thanks, ReadURL() was returning: https://cs7.salesforce.com/ rather than https://cs7-api.salesforce.com/services/soap/c/25.0/